# Create a napari widget that can display an image

Tags: python-napari

I want a napari widget that can display an image, e.g. for permanent display of a fixed colormap.
The goal is to have a widget that can read an image file e.g. .png or .jpg from a file and display it in one of the docking areas to the right or left inside the napari viewer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple widget can be implemented using PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class ImageWidget(QLabel):
    """
    A QLabel widget that displays an image from a file
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
        Initialize the ImageWidget
        """
        super().__init__(parent)

    def set_image(self, file_path):
        """
        Set the image of the widget from a file path
        
        Parameters:
        file_path (str): path to the image file
        """
        pixmap = QPixmap(file_path)
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)

# Create an instance of the ImageWidget
image_widget = ImageWidget()
# Set the image to be displayed in the widget
image_widget.set_image('colormap_white.png')
```

This widget can be used by adding it to the dock area of the napari viewer:

```
viewer.window.add_dock_widget(image_widget,area="left")
```

The result can look like this:

[image: Color scale as image]